Can you forward custom domain traffic to an ip address that is behind a NAT?
I do not know much about this topic so any help would be appreciated. I live in university residences and the internet connection that is provided to us is hosted by Wifinity networks. I run a media server from my residences that hosts a webui that I would like to be able to access through my custom domain.
Previously I have used Cloudflare with its DNS managing tools to forward my domain to my public IP using DDNS running on the server, this then hits my NGINX proxy manager, also running on my server and routes the traffic to the correct port for me to be able to access my webui.
However the issue I am encountering now is because of the way the network is setup by the university residences internet providers, the IP of my router is behind what I assume to be several layers of NAT and so my public IP is listed as one in London (where I do not go to university) and will be the same public IP that anyone who uses Wifinity services will see if they google what their IP address is.
My question is, is there any way for me to be able to route this traffic through the network to my server without having access to routing system that Wifinity uses (I doubt that I would be able to call them up and ask them to give my network its own public IP or anything like that). I have tried a few different ways of getting around this but nothing has worked so far. Any information would be appreciated even if it's telling me that this can't be done.

If you're looking to connect computers across several NATs, you might be
looking to set up a virtual network for your computers that will seem
like the computers are located inside one local network.
Examples of some products that do that :

Tailscale
ZeroTier

See also the post
how to ssh two computers behind NAT and Firewall, without third computer.
